# How to do SMTP Settings for Outbound Emails?

Tags: outbound-email

I'm setting up Outbound Email mailer in my project.

While testing mails are going into defined Pickup folder but mails are not being sent. I know I need to set SMTP settings for it but not able to find out where I need to provide these in the Outboundemail config file.

I tried to use GMail SMTP settings in `<MailBox>` tag but it did not work.

Can somebody please help me on this?

Comment: Thanks for replies but where i need to provide SMTP settings. i'm using gmail as SMTP but not sure where i need to mention SMTP settings(whether in any config file?).

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, Outbound Email can't use GMAIL directly as its SMTP, you need to setup a local SMTP server and have that relay to GMail. So the GMail SMTP settings you need to configure in your local SMTP server, which is why you won't find anything about that in the OE documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Outbound E-mail requires a local SMTP server for sending out e-mails, so you need to set one up on your own environment (for installation instructions, see the third-party documentation for the chosen server).

In the `OutboundEmail.xml` you will configure the folder where Outbound E-mail queues e-mails. You need to configure your SMTP Server to fetch e-mails from this folder.

You can then choose to configure your SMTP server to relay its SMTP requests to the GMail SMTP server, how to do that is again in the third-party documentation for the specific server you installed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to setup  section in your OutboundEmail.xml which allows you to handle outgoing mails.

Once you will properly provide the value for all nodes in  section your outbound mailing will start working and prior to that also verify your local smtp server settings.

And if your pickup folder gets the mails and yet mail is not being sent that means you need to verify your SMTP, either you didn't configure it correctly or your system is failed to connect with SMTP server.