# Issue with sending mail using tridion outbound email feature

Tags: outbound-email

Can anyone suggest if I can use outbound functionality without setting up SMTP locally on CMS server? I have mail relay service setup on some other server, by using which I can send mail from my web server. I am not able to see any configuration file in tridion where I can configure my mail relay address. Can anyone suggest the section in outboundemail.xml configuration, where I can configure my mail relay service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Outbound E-mail Mailer service will generate .EML files in the `<QueueFolder>` location specified in the OutboundEmail.xml configuration file.

You will need something to process the .EML files - to either process and send them directly, or relay them to an email server.  You could use IIS SMTP to process the .EML files (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Hi RJE +1 for your response, I have checked that my outbound application is generating EML file. What do you mean by  "You will need something to process the EML files". Should I write my own code to send the mail now. Fyi, I have mail relay server installed at some other server and I am able to send mail using relay server though .Net application.

Comment: You don't need to write custom code yourself... if you use IIS SMTP and configure it to send all files to your relay server. Otherwise, indeed, you may need to find a way to get the .EML into your mail relay somehow.

Comment: Hi Nuno, I am using Tridion out of the box outbound-email feature and was in the impression of I have to configure my relay server (mailrelay.abc.com) somewhere and then I will be able to test and send the mail through content manager explorer(CME). Right now through CME I am able to generate .EML file in the pickup location and then it is doing nothing.

Comment: Outbound E-mail will not send the .EML files itself - as has been mentioned, you can configure IIS SMTP to pick up these .EML files, and relay them to a email server.

Comment: Thanks Nuno and RJE. I have seen the post related to similar issue here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/how-to-do-smtp-settings-for-outbound-emails?rq=1, and it is clear that Outbound-email functionality is only responsible to create .EML file inside pickup folder. I have configured my local SMTP to use my relay server to send mail and now it is working fine.